# Select a MAX when using a window function that orders with nulls first in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that I'm attempting to optimize and running into some unexpected behavior.

For example, take a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE objects
    (id int, external_id int, timestamp timestamp);

INSERT INTO objects
    (id, external_id, timestamp)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2019-08-16 12:00:00'),
    (2, 1, NULL),
    (3, 2, '2019-08-16 12:00:00'),
    (4, 2, NULL);
```

I use a query as so to partition the `objects` by their `external_id` and then select the maximum value for `timestamp` across the partition:

```
SELECT *, 
max(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY external_id) as max_timestamp, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY external_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC NULLS FIRST, id ASC) 
FROM objects;
```

This produces the following (which is what I'm looking for):

**[Results]**:

```
| id | external_id |            timestamp |        max_timestamp | row_number |
|----|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|------------|
|  2 |           1 |               (null) | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          1 |
|  1 |           1 | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          2 |
|  4 |           2 |               (null) | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          1 |
|  3 |           2 | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          2 |
```

I want to remove the multiple window functions in favor of a single one. For example:

```
SELECT *, 
max(timestamp) OVER w as max_timestamp, 
row_number() OVER w
FROM objects
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY external_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC NULLS FIRST, id ASC);
```

However, doing this produces a different result with the `max_timestamp` set to NULL for half the results:

**[Results]**:

```
| id | external_id |            timestamp |        max_timestamp | row_number |
|----|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|------------|
|  2 |           1 |               (null) |               (null) |          1 |
|  1 |           1 | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          2 |
|  4 |           2 |               (null) |               (null) |          1 |
|  3 |           2 | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z | 2019-08-16T12:00:00Z |          2 |
```

Why would introducing a sort order to the window function have any effect on the return of `max`?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1fcc4/4

Comment: A regular aggregate used as a window function where the window uses an  order by` turns the aggregate into a "rolling aggregate" - evaluated up until the "current row".

Comment: But if you only want the max, then why do you use row_number() to begin with?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I didn't know that - thank you. I need the row_number() because this query is wrapped in another one that filters by a specific row number.